# Syntax error in trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm having trouble when creating a MySQL (5.1) Trigger and I really don't see what I'm doing wrong here. Here's the code :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER CheckSoftware BEFORE INSERT ON Software
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    -- Uppercase the first letter
    SET NEW.name = CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(NEW.name, 1, 1)), SUBSTRING(NEW.name, 2));

    -- If price isn't round
    IF NEW.price != TRUNCATE(NEW.price) THEN
        IF NEW.price - TRUNCATE(NEW.price) <= 0.49 THEN
            -- Sets it to xx.49
            SET NEW.price = TRUNCATE(NEW.price) + 0.49;
        ELSIF (NEW.price - TRUNCATE(NEW.price)) <= 0.99 THEN
            -- Sets it to xx.99
            SET NEW.price = TRUNCATE(NEW.price) + 0.99;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

and what MySQL throws at my face :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') THEN
        IF NEW.price - TRUNCATE(NEW.price) <= 0.49 THEN    
    ' at line 7
```

Thanks a lot for looking at it !

Comment: Is `TRUNCATE` definitely a valid function name in `MySQL` rather than just used for emptying tables?

Comment: Yep, I found it in the MySQL doc, and tested it. Also, the first call to TRUNCATE() doesn't seem to cause any trouble. I tried to replace the second call with other functions (like ROUND()) and still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELIMITER //
    CREATE TRIGGER CheckSoftware BEFORE INSERT ON Software
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        -- Uppercase the first letter
        SET NEW.name = CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(NEW.name, 1, 1)), SUBSTRING(NEW.name, 2));

        -- If price isn't round
        IF NEW.price != TRUNCATE(NEW.price,2) THEN
            IF NEW.price - TRUNCATE(NEW.price,2) <= 0.49 THEN
                -- Sets it to xx.49
                SET NEW.price = TRUNCATE(NEW.price,2) + 0.49;
            ELSIF (NEW.price - TRUNCATE(NEW.price,2)) <= 0.99 THEN
                -- Sets it to xx.99
                SET NEW.price = TRUNCATE(NEW.price,2) + 0.99;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END;
    //

DELIMITER ;
```

truncate function use two parameters!

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed that. Also made me see that what I wanted to use was FLOOR(), not TRUNCATE().

Answer (score -1):

```
DELIMITER # 

CREATE TRIGGER CheckSoftware BEFORE INSERT ON Software
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.name = CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(NEW.name, 1, 1)), SUBSTRING(NEW.name, 2));
    IF NEW.price != TRUNCATE(NEW.price) THEN
      ...
    END IF;
END # -- end of create trigger

DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT - the difference:**

```
...
END; <----
# -- end of create trigger


DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Besides using # as a delimitor instead of //, I don't see a difference.. Is there any ? By the way, using # doesn't solve my problem